# Change Associated Microsoft Account

Tags: microsoft-account

Is there any way to change the Microsoft account associated with a phone without resetting the entire phone? Is there a way to create a second MS account and then make it default? If not through the phone then maybe through PC software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have multiple accounts associated, but the app purchases are always tied to the "main" account, which can **only** be changed with a hard reset.